# How do I provide dimensions of an array to be reshaped as a vector variable?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, reshape, tensor

I want to reshape the array *G* in every iteration, and the shape for new dimensions are coming from vector (say) *tensorSize*. But the MATLAB reshape command does not accept the below given method,

```
tensorSize = [5,6,7,9,3,4];
r=[1,5,25,225,45,9,1];
G1(1) = {randn(1,tensorSize(1),r(2))};
G1(2) = {randn(r(2),tensorSize(2),r(3))};
G1(3) = {randn(r(3),tensorSize(3),r(4))};
G1(4) = {randn(r(4),tensorSize(4),r(5))};
G1(5) = {randn(r(5),tensorSize(5),r(6))};
G1(6) = {randn(r(6),tensorSize(6),1)};

for j = 1:length(tensorSize)-1
    if j == 1
        G = G1(j);
    end
    G = reshape(G,[],r(j+1));
    H = reshape(G1(j+1),r(j+1),[]);
    G = G*H;
    G = reshape(G,tensorSize(1:j+1),[]);
end
```

I have also tried to use other alternatives like:

```
str2num(regexprep(num2str(tensorSize(1:j+1),),'\s+',','))
str2num(strjoin(cellstr(tensorSize(1:j+1)),','))
```

but they create a string and when converted to num, they are not comma separated. So the reshape option does not accept it.

Is there any work around?

Comment: Is `G(:)` what you're looking for?

Comment: No, but I want to reshape G and save it again in G. and for reshaping the array dimensions are from the array *tensorSize* and the last dimension can be empty brackets [ ]. The issue is, the reshape command is not accepting reshape dimensions as a vector variable, instead a comma separated scalars.

Comment: I'm not able to visualize what you're trying to do. On the first iteration in the example, your original `G` is reshaped to `5,6,[]`. Then that new `G` is reshaped to `6,7,[]`? Does `tensorSize` represent the original dimensions of `G`?

Comment: @beaker same interrogation here. Also to my understanding the requested shapes in the current code are successively `5,6,[]`, then `5,6,7,[]`, then `5,6,7,9,[]` etc ... I'm not sure `reshape` can handle these requests (and for it to work `G` should contain an exact multiple of elements for each combination, quite unlikely).

Comment: @Hoki Ah, yes... second iterations reshapes to `5,6,7,[]`. As for the number of elements, that's why I asked if `tensorSize` was the dimensions of `G`. In which case the number of elements *would* be a multiple.

Comment: Given the above assumptions, `reshape(G, [tensorSize(1:j+1) prod(tensorSize(j+2:end))])` will work, but you'll have to check the bounds first.

Comment: ...or just add an extra 1 to the end of `tensorSize`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit for clarification. However, you cannot define your matrix `G1` as in your example (the code doesn't run). Each line of `G1(i)= ...` produce a matrix of different dimension. These matrices cannot be contained in a higher level matrix (you may be able to use a cell array though)

Comment: @beaker I edited the sample. I want to find product of G1(1) to G1(6), that are 3D tensors with every two adjacent tensors have one dimension in common. When I multiply a tensor by another, its dimension will increase by 1. In iter 1, G1(1) is multiplied with G1(2), which are a matrix and a 3D tensor, resulting in a 3D tensor. In iter 2, the result of iter 1, is multiplied with G1(3), resulting in a 4D tensor and so on. So in every iteration, I want the product G to be a tensor of increasing dimension, whose dimension value is given in the array *tensorSize*. Hope, I am more clear now.

Comment: @Hoki I already have them as cell array. But that wasn't a problem I have, I am having an issue in reshaping the matrix into tensor, for which the tensor dimensions are given in a vector. The edit was just to make it clear, what I wanted to do. I just have an issue in the final "reshape" command.

Comment: @Neuling Okay, so some variation on `reshape(G, [tensorSize(1:j+1), ??])`. I'll have more time to look at it when I get off work.

Comment: @beaker Thank you, yes, that's exactly what I want. Looking forward to your help

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `permute` instead? This reshaping doesn’t make sense. Or rather, I don’t understand how it could work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the permute is not an option because, in every iteration G is a matrix and I want to reshape it into a multidimensional array.

Comment: Of course the simple solution is to change your array to a cell array: `tensorSize = {5,6,7,9,3,4}` and use curly braces again to index: `tensorSize{1:j+1}`. That will return a comma-separated list.

Comment: Anyway, your code doesn't run so I'm not able to understand what you're attempting to do.

Comment: @beaker Thank you so much! That's the solution, I was looking for. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @beaker in the comment section below, for proposing this solution!

```
    tensorSize = [5,6,7,9,3,4];
    r=[1,5,25,225,45,9,1];
    G1(1) = {randn(1,tensorSize(1),r(2))};
    G1(2) = {randn(r(2),tensorSize(2),r(3))};
    G1(3) = {randn(r(3),tensorSize(3),r(4))};
    G1(4) = {randn(r(4),tensorSize(4),r(5))};
    G1(5) = {randn(r(5),tensorSize(5),r(6))};
    G1(6) = {randn(r(6),tensorSize(6),1)};
    tensorSizeCell = {zeros(1,length(tensorSize))};

    for i = 1:length(tensorSize)
        tensorSizeCell(i) =  {tensorSize(i)};
    end

    for j = 1:length(tensorSize)-1
        if j == 1
            G = cell2mat(G1(j));
        end
        G = reshape(G,[],r(j+1));
        H = reshape(cell2mat(G1(j+1)),r(j+1),[]);
        G = G*H;
        G = reshape(G,tensorSizeCell{1:j+1},[]);
    end
```